# Como prevenir error de string vacio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Si no le doy un valor a las variables alt y pes el programa se cierra con error.
me dice que retorna un string vacío.
He conseguido que funcione más o menos asignándole valor a los strings, pero supongo que habrá una manera mejor para evitar el error.
El caso es que cuando ejecuto el programa en el campo ediText se muestra un "0" y yo quisiera que no se mostrase nada y que no fallase el código.
Gracias.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val boton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.boton)
        boton.setOnClickListener() {

            val alt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.altura)

            if (alt.text.length == 0) {
                alt.setText("0")

                Toast.makeText(this, "Altura no puede estar vacio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            val pes = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.peso)

            if (pes.text.length == 0) {
                pes.setText("0")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Peso no puede estar vacio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            val altura = alt.text.toString().toDouble()

            val peso = pes.text.toString().toDouble()

            val sum = (peso / ((altura / 100) * (altura / 100)))
            val sum2 = "%.2f".format(sum)
            val resultado = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultado)

            if (alt.text.length > 0 && pes.text.length > 0) {
                resultado.setText(sum2)

            }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: inicializar strings vacíos no te sirve? es decir, `alt.setText("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce cuando llamas `toDouble()` sobre una string vacía. Lo que debes hacer es evitar que se ejecute esa parte cuando los campos no estén completos. Puedes hacerlo moviendo ese código dentro de un `if` o usando `return` para que la función termine antes de hacer el cálculo.

De cualquier forma deberías mover los toast y los `findViewById` afuera del clickListener porque de lo contrario se vuelve un trabajo extra que tiene que repetirse cada vez que presionas el botón.

```
val boton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.boton)
val alt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.altura)
val pes = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.peso)
val resultado = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.resultado)
val toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Completa todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
boton.setOnClickListener {...}
```

Solución con `if`/`else`

```
boton.setOnClickListener {
    if (alt.text.isEmpty() || pes.text.isEmpty()) toast.show()
    else {
        val altura = alt.text.toString().toDouble()
        val peso = pes.text.toString().toDouble()
        val sum = peso / ((altura / 100) * (altura / 100))
        resultado.text = "%.2f".format(sum)
    }
}
```

Solución con `return`

```
boton.setOnClickListener {
    if (alt.text.isEmpty() || pes.text.isEmpty()) return@setOnClickListener toast.show()
    val altura = alt.text.toString().toDouble()
    val peso = pes.text.toString().toDouble()
    val sum = peso / ((altura / 100) * (altura / 100))
    resultado.text = "%.2f".format(sum)
}
```